# JavaScript Regular Expression - Match Everything Except

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a JavaScript template parser, and I'm close to the final solution, however I want to allow whitespace in my template's binding blocks (which I'm matching with regular expressions).

Right now I have the following:

```
var codeblock = new RegExp("%\{[\S)]+\}%", 'g');
```

And given a template line that looks like:

```
<td align="right" style="width: 123px;">%{toFixedEx(#{extendedPrice()}#,2,2)}%</td>
```

Will match:

```
%{toFixedEx(#{extendedPrice()}#,2,2)}%
```

However I want to allow whitespace and line breaks between the `%{` and `}%`, so I tried the following regexp:

```
var codeblock = new RegExp("%\{[\S\s)]+\}%", 'g');
```

Which ends up matching:

```
%{toFixedEx(#{surcharge()}#,2 ,4)}%</td>
<td align="right" style="width: 123px;">%{toFixedEx( #{extendedPrice()}#,2,2)}%
```

What I want to be able to do is match something like:

```
 %{
    if (condition) {
       toFixedEx(#{surcharge()}#,2 ,4)
    }
    else {
       toFixedEx(0,2,4)
    }
 }%
```

Where the match ends at `}%` instead of continuing on to the last closing brace in the template. I tried subtraced character classes, however it does not look like they work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var codeblock = new RegExp("%\{[\S\s]+?\}%", 'g');
```

`+?` and `*?` means: Match as less as possible to meet the condition of the next part of the RE.

I have also removed the parenthesis,`)`, from your RE, because `[\S\s]` matches every character (including newlines).

Comment: Another note (to future readers): Many programmers use `.`, expecting to match as much as possible. `.` doesn't match newlines, however. To match everything, `[\S\s]` should be used, which means "any non-whitespace character *or* any white-space character".